# WSO2 ESB Proxy service Configuration Issue

Tags: wso2-esb

How to configure Proxy service (pass through proxy or WSDL Based Proxy) through Eclipse based ESB Developer tool.

Issues Iam facing 
1) Actual endpoint operations are converted into mediate opertations

2) Header part is missing from from the soap-enevlope of proxy service which is actually present in the endpoint service.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a *ESBConfigProject*
- Go to *src -> main -> synapse-config -> endpoints*
- Right click on the endpoints folder and choose *New -> Endpoint* and select *Create A New Endpoint* radio button in the wizard and click *Next*
- Provide Endpoint Name, Endpoint Type, Address and click Finish. The endpoint will be created in the directory endpoints
- Go to *src -> main -> synapse-config -> proxy-services*
- Right click on the proxy-services folder and choose *New -> Proxy Service* and select *Create A New Proxy Service* radio button in the wizard and click *Next*
- Provide Proxy Service Name and Proxy Service Type. In the Advanced Configuration part, select Target Endpoint as Predefined Endpoint and select the endpoint in the dropdown list box
- Click Finish and the proxy service service will be created.

Thanks